# A flat strip cannot be twisted isometrically

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

If a flat strip is twisted it would undergo length changes away from plane of osculation as the bi-normal rotates, accompanied by reduction in Gauss curvature K without isometry. During pure bending a principal curvature remains zero.So,

```
        A flat strip can be bent, but cannot be isometrically twisted.
```

Is the above assertion (no isometric embedding of flat strip $ \mathbb R^2 $ into $ \mathbb R^3 $ by twisting ) correct?

EDIT 1:

If such a mapping is possible, please indicate one simple parametrization.

EDIT 2:

I wish to make a distinction between bending and twisting. For example the area between two helices of a right circular cylinder:

> $$ (\cos (u+v) , \sin (u+v) , v)  $$

is bent, but not twisted.

EDIT 3:

In isometric mapping aka *bending*, differential lengths and hence included angles do not change. We have the Christoffel symbols operating  through $ E,F,G, K, k_g $ etc. of first fundamental form of lengths.

Bending and Twisting are generically referred together in mechanics of materials. But it presents a great difficulty in mathematics of classical surface theory of Gauss; twisting is  quite a thing apart, as differential lengths are allowed to change, undergoing strain or dilatation.

Twisting is not isometric, K changes occur in mappings and twisting, twisting is not covered by Christoffel symbols or the first fundamental form of surface theory.

There are two types of non-isometric mappings. Dilation and Warping. Von Kármán relations give changes of K due to changes of differential lengths/angles ( as strains).

$$ \frac { \partial^2 \epsilon_x }{ \partial y^2 } + \frac { \partial^2 \epsilon_y }{ \partial x^2 } -\frac { \partial  \epsilon_{xy} }{\partial x\, \partial y\ } \approx -\Delta K $$

A definition of dilations/warping of surfaces with derivatives  differential lengths/ coefficients as extension of Christoffel symbols is needed to find *changes* in Gauss curvature or geodesic curvature.

If a flat strip is twisted and its $K$ reduces, a definition is  necessary to find new $ K,k_g $ etc. Likewise  when a circular cylinder has edges dilated then it becomes a catenoid isometric to a helicoid, what relations are needed to define it? Also if the edges contract in a given manner of variation we have a portion of an ellipsoid like positive $K$ dome forming, but I do not know how to calculate it because an ODE or PDE is just not available.

Please comment on the above, with any available definitions.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: "Flat embeddings of the Möbius strip in $\mathbb{R}^3$." 
*Commun. Appl. Nonlinear Anal.* 9, No. 2, 31-50 (2002). [ZbMath link](https://zbmath.org/1035.53006).

Comment: Thanks. The Moebius stip is not developable. In  visualizations of sufficiently wide $u,v$  parameteric domains  we can clearly see negative curvatures.

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you are asking.  If you are asking whether every flat surface is (locally) ruled, the answer is 'yes'.  However, there are (smooth) Möbius bands in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that have Gauss curvature $K\equiv0$, so your definition of 'twist' must not forbid this if your statement is to be correct.

Comment: Your interest seems to originate in mechanics.  To mathematicians your discussion of twisting is not clear.  Now it turns out that it is *not* isometric.  Could you provide links to references that give definitions for these notions?

Comment: The mathematics of continuum mechanics, and fluid mechanics  are unified and taught together. Von Kármán ( aerodynamics engineer ) has given the above PDE.

Comment: The definition of twisting/dilation is *not* isometric as the right hand side shows change in $K$.

Comment: @Narasimham: to get help on this site you need to ask a mathematical question. In your case this inculdes giving a mathematical definition of twisting. Saying that "twisting is not isometric"  does not qualify as a definition.

Comment: I am requesting for references if any are available. for the simplest examples... It does not feel good  that a cylinder cannot be parametrized  and warped to become a catenoid or contracted to an elliptic ring formation in a non-isometry mode.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek My query is about the mathematical definition of non-isometry of twisting ( K decrease) or dilatation (K increase). It is essentially about surface element length changes....

Comment: @MikhailKatz :  Just posted at iMechanica  for help.( Prescribing Surface Strains to change Gauss curvature) http://imechanica.org/node/20231